# How to accomplish a Multi-pane design for ios using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I am trying to accomplish a multi-pane (similar to master-detail) design for an iOS app using Swift. Here are the requirements:

1. When in Portrait mode the panes have to be layered vertically, master pane on top details on bottom, each pane occupying 50% of the available space.
2. When in landscape mode, the panes have to display side by side, each pane occupying 50% of the available space.
3. Ability to close/collapse the details pane and only show master (master has to adjust to full screen when details is collapsed)

I looked into using `UISplitViewController` but I did not find a way to make it display top/bottom. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What iOS version is your deployment target?

Comment: IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 8.3;